# Comprobar si un valor esta en la lista en C

Tags: c

Llevo un par de horas haciendo un codigo en C y una parte necesita comprobar si una variable esta en una lista.

Me gustaría saber si existe un codigo equivalente en C de este hecho en python.

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var1 = 1

if var1 in lista:
    print("En la lista")
else
    print("No esta en la lista")
```

Comment: No, no existe, tienes que implentarla tu mismo o usar alguna librería externa que implemente dicha funcionalidad.

Comment: Puedes consultar la [librería estándar de C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header) o la de [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te comparto este codigo simple, donde el principio es el mismo, recorrer el arreglo que tienes y comprobar con cada elemento si `var1` es igual. Espero te sirva como guia.

```
int main() {
  int lista[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; //Definición de la lista
  int var1 = 1; //Elemento a buscar.
  int found = 0; //Bandera para indicar si encontramos el elemento, inicialmente es "Falso"

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { //Se itera sobre lista
    if (lista[i] == var1) { //Preguntamos si el elemento en turno es igual al elemento a buscar
      found = 1; //Inidicamos que son iguales
      break;
    }
  }

  if (found) { //Preguntamos si encotramos un elemento igual
    printf("En la lista\n");
  } else {
    printf("No esta en la lista\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No se como algo tan simple no se me había ocurrido.
Eso sin duda me lo ha arreglado, lo pondré en una función y lo iré usando a medida que el codigo lo requiera, grácias!

Comment: El desafío será ponerlo en una función @jefreyhernandezrodriguez ya que el código que te han compartido no es extensible ni re utilizable.

Comment: He modificado unas cuantas cosas para que me vaya en una función y me ha funcionado, eliminando la ultima parte del if, cambiando el tipo de bandera, en el for, que me haga el rango del largo de la lista y que me haga un return de la bandera hace lo que necesito para mi codigo.
Igualmente, gracias por la observación!